# Was bedeutet vereignen und Vereignung?

Tags: meaning, etymology, regional, heidegger

Was bedeutet vereignen und Vereignung?

Ich würde es auch gerne wissen, wie die Etymologie ist und die Verbindung mit der Vorsilbe "ver" und das Verb "eignen". Ich habe es gesucht aber ich habe gefunden dass es auf Hochdeutsch nicht gewöhnlich ist. Ist es in manchem Dialekt üblich? Die Bedeutung, die ich gefunden habe, hängt mit Verkauf oder Vertauschen zusammen, aber Ich suche dieses Konzept in dem philosophischen Sinn.

Ich habe es in einem Buch über Heidegger gefunden. Das Fragment ist:

> "Keine Macht der Welt und kein Gott wird mein Denken jemals aus der Vereignung in das Seyn selber herausreissen. Niemals wird sich das Denken in seinem Wesen verleugnen"

–

Comment: In welchem Kontext (bei welche\*r Autor\*in, welch\*er Philosoph\*in) bist du denn auf das Wort gestoßen? Es handelt sich nicht um ein alltagssprachliches Wort des Deutschen.

Comment: Ich habe es in einem Buch über Heidegger gefunden. Das Fragment ist "

Keine Macht der Welt und kein Gott wird mein Denken jemals aus der Vereignung in das Seyn selber herausreissen. Niemals wird sich das Denken in seinem Wesen verleugnen"

Comment: Um die Sprache Heideggers zu verstehen, sollte man in einen Kommentar, in die Sekundärliteratur schauen. Heidegger hat eine sehr eigentümliche Sprechweise, seine Wortschöpfungen bzw. sein altertümelnder Sprachgebrauch sind oft mit hintergründigen Theorien beladen.

Comment: @TioMiserias Ich habe Deinen Kommentar mal in die Frage eingefügt. Da nicht jeder alle Kommentare liest und Kommentare auch mal gelöscht werden, sollte relevante Information immer direkt in der Frage stehen. :)  Willkommen an Bord!

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Danke für deine Kommentar. Kennst du ein Buch, das du mir empfehlen kannst?

Comment: @Arsak Danke sehr! :)

Comment: Ich kenne mich mit Heidegger nicht aus. Aber ich habe das hier gefunden: https://books.google.de/books?id=PKLCBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT176&lpg=PT176&dq=vereignung+heidegger&source=bl&ots=pIKD_IZTts&sig=ACfU3U3Nj-MiLN9Bym-HOBcmTyqCPRPGtQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjH84e_pP7pAhVEyKYKHSoEDfQQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=vereignung%20heidegger&f=false Heidegger scheint "ver-eignen" im Zusammenhang mit "er-eignen" und "ent-eignen" zu sehen. Ansonsten vielleicht Andreas Luckner: "Martin Heidegger. Sein und Zeit"

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach danke :)

Answer (score 5):

Laut [Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/displayLinkInfo.tcl?sigle=DWB&formid=GV00948) bedeutet *vereignen* das Übertragen von eigenem Besitz in den eines Fremden. Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, dass das Wort heute noch in einer Region gebräuchlich ist und würde als es (stark) **veraltet** betrachten.

*Vereignung* (als Substantiv groß zu schreiben) ebenso, siehe [dort](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/displayLinkInfo.tcl?sigle=DWB&formid=GV00949).

Comment: Hat diese Wörterbuchbedeutung etwas damit zu tun, wie Heidegger das Wort benutzt?

Comment: @DavidVogt: Zugegebenermaßen nicht, aber das war zum Antwortzeitpunkt auch noch nicht  Bestandteil der Frage. Die Frage des Titels wird beantwortet.